# How to find the url handler in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

if I have some form to send in the site how can I find where is the script handling that form?

for example a form with

`action="/#wpcf7-f20-w1-o1"`

where to find the handling script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typical of the `Contact Form 7` Plugin. You need to hook it to get the values. You can have a look at the [Unofficial Developer Documentation](http://xaviesteve.com/3298/wordpress-contact-form-7-hook-unofficial-developer-documentation-and-examples/) and the [docs](http://contactform7.com/docs/) for more details.

Here is an example on how to get the values posted:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'callback_fn' );

function callback_fn( $data )
{
// manipulate $data to get values
}
```

Answer (score 1):

wpcf7 looks like it's from [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/). Check your plugins directory. BTW, [WordPress Answers SE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) would be a better place to ask any WordPress-related questions.